# serving static json data with question mark in filename in expressjs

Tags: express, mocking

I am attempting to to serve json data statically from the filesystem in order to mock an api.

I was using deployd in my stack before and able to serve /users/names?id=123 from ./users/names?id=123/index.html, but I wanted to remove that dependency and just rely on express like so:

```
var express = require('express'),
  cors = require('cors'),
  app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('api'));

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('API Mock Server listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Unfortunately express is not serving the JSON file when i access it at ./users/names?id=123/index.html, I also tried renaming that index.html to: ./users/names?id=123 to no avail

Answer (score 1):

You should percent encode the '?' when you access it in your browser.

so try *./users/names%3Fid=123/index.html*

See [File URI encoding rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

Comment: This sort of works, in that i can now access the JSON file, but doesnt  work in that my mock API is no longer on the same path as the actual api... any way to get express to serve it with the ? in the url?

Comment: I think unless you also rename your physical filepaths, it will be difficult to get it working since the '?' isn't really recommended as part of a name file. Maybe you should look at serving your API parameters through a different standard, using something like /users/names/id/123 would raise another level of complexity in terms of tree exploration but is feasible.